# Eclipse svn take changes from one specific update

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

Is it possible to take back changes for one specific update in local work-space?

For example there are 5 different commits made by someone else: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. All commits are to different files. I have updated my local work-space with all of them, but it turns out number 3 has a bug in it and I don't want it in my local work-space cos project wont run. Can i somehow change back the files edited in commit nr. 3 to their previous state? I could look up their history and do it manually but if many files where changed that could be complicated.

I am using eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid to use the `svn` command line interface, the command you're looking for is

```
svn merge -c -3 .
```

This will reverse-merge commit no. 3 or, put differently, will undo all changes that were committed in revision 3.